# java producer consumer issue-make thread wait until others have finished before completing

Tags: java, multithreading, time, synchronization, producer-consumer

I am currently doing a producer consumer problem with multiple threads. There are 1000 bytes available at first and 500 have been taken up by using the RAM nad drivers, leaving me to work with 500 for the threads. There are to be 4 producers, as follows:

1. A thread to start a BubbleWitch2 session of 10 seconds, which requires 100 bytes of RAM per
   second
2. A thread to start a Spotify stream of 20 seconds, which requires 250 bytes of RAM per second.
3. System and management threads, which, together, require 50 bytes of RAM per second, and
   execute for a random length of time, once invoked.
4. A thread to install a new security update of 2 KB, which will be stored to disk, and requires 150 bytes of RAM per second while installing. Assume sufficient disk capacity in the system to support this thread.

The program is meant to cease execution when the security update has finished. Ideally, this should be achieved without setting priorities on the threads. It was working earlier but now when I run the program, the security thread is finishing in the middle and spotify is finishing laugh. Are there any mistakes that may be causing this? I have included my code below. I have yet to assign all of the byte sizes to the threads and buffer.

My main method.

```
/**
 * Created by User on 10/08/2014.
 */
public class ProducerConsumerTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            Buffer c = new Buffer();
            BubbleWitch2 p1 = new BubbleWitch2(c, 1);
            Processor c1 = new Processor(c, 2);
            Spotify p2 = new Spotify(c, 3);
            SystemManagement p3 = new SystemManagement(c,4);
            securityUpdate p4 = new securityUpdate(c,5, p1,p2,p3);

            p1.setName("BubbleWitch2 ");
            p2.setName("Spotify ");
            p3.setName("System Management ");
            p4.setName("Security Update ");

            c1.start();
            p1.start();
            p2.start();
            p3.start();
            p4.start();

            p2.join();
            p3.join();
            p4.join();
            System.exit(0);

        }
    }
```

My buffer/cubbyhole class

```
/**
 * Created by User on 10/08/2014.
 */
class Buffer {
    private int contents;
    private boolean available = false;
    public synchronized int get() {
        while (available == false) {
            try {
                wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        available = false;
        notifyAll();
        return contents;
    }
    public synchronized void put(int value) {
        while (available == true) {
            try {
                wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        contents = value;
        available = true;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

My Consumer class

```
class Processor extends Thread {
    private Buffer cubbyhole;
    private int number;
    public Processor(Buffer c, int number) {
        cubbyhole = c;
        this.number = number;
    }
    public void run() {
        int value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
            value = cubbyhole.get();
            System.out.println("Processor #"
                    + this.number
                    + " got: " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

My spotify producer class

```
class Spotify extends Thread {
    private Buffer buffer;
    private int number;
    private int bytes;

    public Spotify(Buffer c, int number) {
        buffer = c;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            buffer.put(i);
            System.out.println(getName() + this.number
                    + " put: " + i);
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        System.out.println("Spotify has finished executing.");
        System.out.println("*****************************");

    }
}
```

My bubblewitch producer class

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.lang.System;
/**
 * Created by User on 10/08/2014.
 */
class BubbleWitch2 extends Thread {
    private Buffer buffer;
    private int number;
    private int bytes;

    public BubbleWitch2(Buffer c, int number) {
        buffer = c;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            buffer.put(i);
            System.out.println(getName() + this.number
                    + " put: " + i);
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        System.out.println("BubbleWitch2 has finished executing.");
        System.out.println("*****************************");
    }
}
```

My system Management producer class

```
  class SystemManagement extends Thread {
        private Buffer buffer;
        private int number, min = 1, max = 15;
        private int loopCount = (int) (Math.random() * ( max - min ));

        public SystemManagement(Buffer c, int number) {
            buffer = c;
            this.number = number;
        }

        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++) {
                buffer.put(i);
                System.out.println(getName() + this.number
                        + " put: " + i);
                try {
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            }
            System.out.println("*****************************");
            System.out.println("System Management has finished executing.");
            System.out.println("*****************************");
        }
    }
```

My security update class

```
/**
 * Created by User on 14/08/2014.
 */
import java.lang.*;
import java.lang.System;

/**
 * Created by User on 11/08/2014.
 */
class securityUpdate extends Thread {
    private Buffer buffer;
    private int number;
    private int bytes = 150;
    private int process = 0;

    public securityUpdate (Buffer c, int number, BubbleWitch2 bubbleWitch2, Spotify spotify, SystemManagement systemManagement) throws InterruptedException {
        buffer = c;
        this.number = number;
        bubbleWitch2.join();
        spotify.join();
        systemManagement.join();
    }

    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            buffer.put(i);
            System.out.println(getName() + this.number
                    + " put: " + i);
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        System.out.println("Security Update has finished executing.");
        System.out.println("*****************************");
    }
}
```

I want to be able to make it run last without hardcoding a different number in the count as I will be required to calculate in code how long it takes to run at a size of 2000 bytes at 150 bytes per second, which would make hardcoding irrelevant. Has anyone any ideas?

Comment: Hm.. I am not sure I understand your question, can you rephrase it? But some nits: Use uppercase letter for classes (SecurityUpdate). Do not add logic - especially not blocking methods like join() in an constructor. Do you really need multiple classes for the various producers/consumers? Could you use just one with params for name, rate and count?

Comment: i basically want the threads to complete according to the specified times in a certain order, but the security update thread must finish last as it is the end of the program. once the security thread and the whole program has finished, I want to have code to calculate the length of time to the security thread took to run. Will this mean removing the for loop where I have specified <10? Are joins a bad idea here? I will rename the thread with uppercase. I had thought about just one class but right now i am finding it easier for multiple producers since I haven't studied threads for long.

Comment: Hm, I think it is best to use join() with all threads at the end of the run method of the security thread in that case (and remove all other joins). No need to sleep or calculate.

Comment: does that explain it any easier?

Comment: I've been advised that we need to calculate the time it takes to run the thread, rather than assigning a set time of say, 20 seconds. The criteria says "Include code in your solution which calculates the average time an application request has to wait in the
buffer until it is allocated RAM resources and processed. Code should also be included in your solution to
calculate the length of time to install the security update.
The program should cease execution once the security update has been installed."

Comment: The "calculate the time" sounds to me more like a measurement. Because you simulate the queuing behavior, so one wants to get a result measured (as an average rate or runtime or similiar). (Just guessing).

Comment: well would you know how to calculate the time? the thread is 2000 bytes and will run at 150 bytes per second, giving just over 13 seconds for completion. So if I am supposed to calculate the time of the thread, does this mean putting a random value inside of the for loop in that class instead of 10 for example? it also says "Generate exit times from the operating system based on the duration of the session,
and use this value as the value entered into the bounded buffer." I am not sure exactly what this means, would you know?

Comment: I guess one can only solve this when attending the class. Anyway, it sounds like the two threads should simply check every second if the download and the other time limited threads are still alive, and can leave the run method otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this below modified code of yours using executor framework which is simpler:-

```
public class ProducerConsumerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        BlockingQueue<Integer> c = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(1);
        CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(3);

        Processor c1 = new Processor(c, 2, doneSignal);

        BubbleWitch2 p1 = new BubbleWitch2(c, 1, doneSignal);        
        Spotify p2 = new Spotify(c, 3, doneSignal);
        SystemManagement p3 = new SystemManagement(c,4, doneSignal);
        SecurityUpdate p4 = new SecurityUpdate(c,5, doneSignal);

        p1.setName("BubbleWitch2 ");
        p2.setName("Spotify ");
        p3.setName("System Management ");
        p4.setName("Security Update ");

        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        exec.submit(c1);
        exec.submit(p1);
        exec.submit(p2);
        exec.submit(p3);        

        Future<?> securityFuture = exec.submit(p4);

        try {
            while(securityFuture.get()!=null) {

            }           
            exec.shutdown();
            while(exec.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {

            }
            exec.shutdownNow();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
class Processor extends Thread {
    private BlockingQueue<Integer> cubbyhole;
    private int number;
    private CountDownLatch doneSignal;

    public Processor(BlockingQueue<Integer> c, int number,CountDownLatch doneSignal) {
        cubbyhole = c;
        this.number = number;
        this.doneSignal = doneSignal;
    }
    public void run() {
        int value = 0;
       // for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        while(true) {
            try {
                value = cubbyhole.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Processor #"
                    + this.number
                    + " got: " + value);
        }
        //doneSignal.countDown();
    }
}

class Spotify extends Thread {
    private BlockingQueue<Integer> buffer;
    private int number;
    private int bytes;
    private CountDownLatch doneSignal;

    public Spotify(BlockingQueue<Integer> c, int number, CountDownLatch doneSignal) {
        buffer = c;
        this.number = number;
        this.doneSignal = doneSignal;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            try {
                buffer.put(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(getName() + this.number
                    + " put: " + i);           
        }
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        System.out.println("Spotify has finished executing.");
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        doneSignal.countDown();
    }
}

class BubbleWitch2 extends Thread {
    private BlockingQueue<Integer> buffer;
    private int number;
    private int bytes;
    private CountDownLatch doneSignal;

    public BubbleWitch2(BlockingQueue<Integer> c, int number, CountDownLatch doneSignal) {
        buffer = c;
        this.number = number;
        this.doneSignal = doneSignal;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                buffer.put(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(getName() + this.number
                    + " put: " + i);

        }
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        System.out.println("BubbleWitch2 has finished executing.");
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        doneSignal.countDown();
    }
}

class SystemManagement extends Thread {
    private BlockingQueue<Integer> buffer;
    private int number, min = 1, max = 15;
    private int loopCount = (int) (Math.random() * ( max - min ));
    private CountDownLatch doneSignal;

    public SystemManagement(BlockingQueue<Integer> c, int number, CountDownLatch doneSignal) {
        buffer = c;
        this.number = number;
        this.doneSignal = doneSignal;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++) {
            try {
                buffer.put(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(getName() + this.number
                    + " put: " + i);

        }
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        System.out.println("System Management has finished executing.");
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        doneSignal.countDown();
    }
}

class SecurityUpdate extends Thread {
    private BlockingQueue<Integer> buffer;
    private int number;
    private int bytes = 150;
    private int process = 0;
    private CountDownLatch doneSignal;

    public SecurityUpdate (BlockingQueue<Integer> c, int number, CountDownLatch doneSignal) {
        buffer = c;
        this.number = number;
        this.doneSignal = doneSignal;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            doneSignal.await();         
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                buffer.put(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(getName() + this.number
                    + " put: " + i);

        }
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        System.out.println("Security Update has finished executing.");
        System.out.println("*****************************");
    }
}
```

Do let me know if you have any questions

Comment: it runs pretty much the same as mine but I have no idea what that future etc means. Would you know how to calculate the average wait times of the threads or how to make them wait for a buffer that can only process 200 bytes per second?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but you are joining threads in `securityUpdate`'s constructor:

```
bubbleWitch2.join();
spotify.join();
systemManagement.join();
```

These joins happen before the threads are started, so they are no-ops.

Again, I don't have a full understanding of the problem here, but it seems like you're trying to have securityUpdate wait for those three threads to complete.  If so, you might wish to move those calls to `join()` into the `run()` method.

Or something similar.  Good luck.

Comment: I've managed to get past that but am facing a problem here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373149/producer-consumer-average-wait-times-not-outputting-buffer-query