# Producer Consumer-Average Wait times not outputting/buffer query

Tags: java, multithreading, buffer, wait, producer-consumer

I am currently making a hypothetical producer consumer problem using java. The object is to have an operating system which is 1000 bytes, but only 500 bytes available to use for threads as 500 bytes have already been consumed by drivers and other operations. The threads are as follows:

1. A thread to start a BubbleWitch2 session of 10 seconds, which requires 100 bytes of RAM per
   second
2. A thread to start a Spotify stream of 20 seconds, which requires 250 bytes of RAM per second
   You should also take into account the fact that the operating system is simultaneously supporting system
   activity and managing the processor, memory and disk space of the device on which it is installed.
   Therefore, additionally create:
3. System and management threads, which, together, require 50 bytes of RAM per second, and
   execute for a random length of time, once invoked.
4. A thread to install a new security update of 2 KB, which will be stored to disk, and requires 150
   bytes of RAM per second while installing. Assume sufficient disk capacity in the system to support
   this thread.

The operating system has only capacity for 200 bytes per second, therefore a larger thread such as spotify will experience delays or be forced to wait. I have used code which as far as I can tell, implements this. I am also required to generate exit times which I have done with timestamps and to calculate average waiting times for threads.

I have included code in my solution for the average waiting times with system.out.print but no matter what I do, it is not actually outputting the times at all-as if they did not exist.

I am also not sure if the buffer size limitations are working as it is a matter of milliseconds-is there any way to tell if this is working from the code below?

My main method.

```
   public class ProducerConsumerTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            Buffer c = new Buffer();
            BubbleWitch2 p1 = new BubbleWitch2(c,1);
            Processor c1 = new Processor(c, 1);
            Spotify p2 = new Spotify(c, 2);
            SystemManagement p3 = new SystemManagement(c, 3);
            SecurityUpdate p4 = new SecurityUpdate(c, 4, p1, p2, p3);


            p1.setName("BubbleWitch2 ");
            p2.setName("Spotify ");
            p3.setName("System Management ");
            p4.setName("Security Update ");

            p1.setPriority(10);
            p2.setPriority(10);
            p3.setPriority(10);
            p4.setPriority(5);

            c1.start();
            p1.start();
            p2.start();
            p3.start();
            p4.start();

            p2.join();
            p3.join();
            p4.join();
            System.exit(0);

        }
    }


My buffer class

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

/**
 * Created by Rory on 10/08/2014.
 */
class Buffer {
    private int contents, count = 0, process = 0;
    private boolean available = false;
    private long start, end, wait, request= 0;
    private DateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss:SSS");



    public synchronized int get() {
        while (process <= 500) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        process -= 200;
        System.out.println("CPU After Process " + process);
        notifyAll();
        return contents;
    }

    public synchronized void put(int value) {
        while (process >= 1000) {
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            wait = end - start;
            count++;
            request += wait;
            System.out.println("Application Request Wait Time: " + time.format(wait));
            process += value;
            contents = value;
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

My security update class

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.lang.System;


/**
 * Created by Rory on 11/08/2014.
 */
class SecurityUpdate extends Thread {
    private Buffer buffer;
    private int number;
    private int bytes = 150;
    private int process = 0;

    public SecurityUpdate(Buffer c, int number, BubbleWitch2 bubbleWitch2, Spotify spotify, SystemManagement systemManagement) throws InterruptedException {
        buffer = c;
        this.number = number;
        bubbleWitch2.join();
        spotify.join();
        systemManagement.join();

    }

    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            buffer.put(i);
            System.out.println(getName() + this.number
                    + " put: " + i);
            try {
                sleep(1500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        System.out.println("Security Update has finished executing.");
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
    }
}
```

My processor class

```
class Processor extends Thread {
    private Buffer processor;
    private int number;

    public Processor(Buffer c, int number) {
        processor = c;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void run() {
        int value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
            value = processor.get();
            System.out.println("Processor #"
                    + this.number
                    + " got: " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

My bubblewitch class

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.lang.System;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

/**
 * Created by Rory on 10/08/2014.
 */
class BubbleWitch2 extends Thread {
    private Buffer buffer;
    private int number;
    private int bytes = 100;
    private int duration;

    public BubbleWitch2(Buffer c, int pduration) {
        buffer = c;

        duration = pduration;
    }

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            buffer.put(bytes);
            System.out.println(getName() + this.number
                    + " put: " + i);
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long timeTaken = endTime - startTime;
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();


        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        System.out.println("BubbleWitch2 has finished executing.");
        System.out.println("Time taken to execute was " +timeTaken+ " milliseconds");
        System.out.println("Time Bubblewitch2 thread exited Processor was " + new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
    }
}
```

My system management

```
class SystemManagement extends Thread {
    private Buffer buffer;
    private int number, min = 1, max = 15;
    private int loopCount = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min));
    private int bytes = 50;
    private int process = 0;


    public SystemManagement(Buffer c, int number) {
        buffer = c;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++) {
            buffer.put(50);
            System.out.println(getName() + this.number
                    + " put: " + i);
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        System.out.println("System Management has finished executing.");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
    }
}
```

My spotify class
    import java.sql.Timestamp;

```
/**
 * Created by Rory on 11/08/2014.
 */
class Spotify extends Thread {
    private Buffer buffer;
    private int number;
    private int bytes = 250;


    public Spotify(Buffer c, int number) {
        buffer = c;
        this.number = number;
    }


    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            buffer.put(bytes);
            System.out.println(getName() + this.number
                    + " put: " + i);
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long timeTaken = endTime - startTime;
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));


        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        System.out.println("Spotify has finished executing.");
        System.out.println("Time taken to execute was " + timeTaken + " milliseconds");
        System.out.println("Time that Spotify thread exited Processor was " + date);

        System.out.println("-----------------------------");


    }
}
```

I may need to add timestamps to one or two classes yet but does anyone have any idea how to get my average times to actually print out? Or what is preventing it and if the buffer limitation is effectively being shown here(given that we are talking about milliseconds?)
Thanks.

Comment: please tell us which system out print is not working?

Comment: the system out prints that are not working are those in the buffer class referring to the cpu after process and those that refer to the application request time, though I realise now I forgot to write average in that. even so, it is still not printing.

Comment: I was also wondering, do my time variables need to share the same name across all of my classes? for example should it be starttime and endtime in all threads instead of spotstarttime, bubblestarttime etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why sys out's are not printing is because of the below condition in your buffer class:-

```
public synchronized void put(int value) {
        while (process >= 1000) {
            .....
            notifyAll();
        }
}
```

this condition never gets satisified as the process never is greater than 1000

This is the reason why your Processor thread also gets stuck because when it calls get() it finds that the process is less than 500 and hence it indefinitely waits when it reaches the wait() line of code.

Rectifying the process condition appropriately in your put should let your missing sys out get printed

```
public synchronized void put(int value) {
        if(process <= 500) {
            process+=value;
        } else {
            //while (process >= 1000) {
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                wait = end - start;
                count++;
                request += wait;
                System.out.println("Application Request Wait Time: " + time.format(wait));
                process += value;
                contents = value;               
            //}
        }
        notifyAll();
    }
```

Comment: so what should I change it too? I changed the 1000 in the while to 500 but it is still not printing?

Comment: or how can I rectify it? Are there any other errors within the code?

Comment: @paul: just think about what belongs *inside* the `while` loop and what belongs to the *outside*.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, is it possible to put all of the extra content including notify all inside of the while loops? I am just after running my program after making these changes and now the processor is not showing up in the output-is that something to do with this code?

Comment: @paul it looks like you have given the check for process as 1000 in the put method equating it to 1000 bytes and in spotify thread you are trying to put 250 value to buffer because it takes 250 bytes as per your question but the whole design of mapping bytes required by a program to run with the integer values which you are putting in buffer and checking if process >= 1000 is confusing and I am not sure if its the exact representation of your problem at hand or would it give you the solution to your problem.

Comment: essentially there are 500 bytes that can be used as 500 bytes are already occupied. Are my while loop values wrong? What I want to do is to make it wait if the thread is larger than 200 bytes as the buffer can only process 200 bytes per second. Then I want it to calculate the wait time and output that. Would you know how to fix it?

Comment: @paul I have modified the put based on your explaination. This code still isnt foolproof. Try this and test your scenarios and do let us know if any of your requirement is not met

Comment: thank you, it is printing the CPU after process and it is printing the printing the wait time, although the wait time is 0 seconds. Does this mean that it is working dynamically then? With your edited code, I have managed to get the processor output to appear once more so thank you again. With regards to the average wait time, do I calculate that using time taken of each thread divided by the number of threads? or would it be something like wait+wait/2 for example?

Comment: what I mean is, is it possible to get the wait average if the wait average is always showing as 00:00:00? Does it need a timestamp or something else in the code to fill it with data?

Comment: should the waits being appearing the whole way through the output? mine stop just after halfway

Comment: thanks it won't let me rate so I clicked the tick mark to be green if that's what you mean?

Comment: donot format the wait time using dateformat as the wait time would usually be in milliseconds or seconds and not in minutes (my guess). Also to compute the average wait time divide the value of request variable (in the put method of buffer) with the number of threads again this is my understanding you are the better judge

Answer (score 2):

If you want securityupdate thread to always run at the last then the correct way of using join within that thread is as below:-

```
class SecurityUpdate extends Thread {
    private Buffer buffer;
    private int number;
    private int bytes = 150;
    private int process = 0;
    private BubbleWitch2 bubbleWitch2;
    private Spotify spotify;
    private SystemManagement systemManagement;

    public SecurityUpdate(Buffer c, int number, BubbleWitch2 bubbleWitch2, Spotify spotify, SystemManagement systemManagement) throws InterruptedException {
        buffer = c;
        this.number = number;
        this.bubbleWitch2 = bubbleWitch2;
        this.spotify = spotify;
        this.systemManagement = systemManagement;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            bubbleWitch2.join();
            spotify.join();
            systemManagement.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {      
        }
        System.out.println("Finally starting the security update");
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            buffer.put(bytes);  // Paul check if it should be i or bytes
            System.out.println(getName() + this.number
                    + " put: " + i);
            try {
                sleep(1500);  // Paul why is this made to sleep 1500 seconds?
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        System.out.println("Security Update has finished executing.");
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh I made it sleep to 15 seconds as the total size of it 2000 bytes, to be run at a rate of 150 bytes per second. Is this not correct or is there another way of doing this? Should it be random?

Comment: I do want the outputs to be in milliseconds as well, it is ok. I have run the entire program and sometimes the average wait time will be 00:00:00 and other random times now it will be 00:00:07 or something. Is this random nature normal?

Comment: @paul you are making the security thread to sleep for 1.5 seconds .Check with your requirement if its correct. Regarding the randomness of wait time yes it would vary but i feel even the Processor thread needs to be made to sleep for 1000 milliseconds.